# Get Standard MultiSelect Options into a page

Tags: apex, multi-select

I want to create a multiselect list on an apex page that displays an objects standard options. Below is the code I'm using:

```
public List<String> getMSList(){
           List<String> pickMSL= new List<String>();
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.Products_To_Price__c.getDescribe();
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> vals = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
            for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : vals){
                pickMSL.add(pickListVal.getLabel());
        }     
        return pickMSL;
    }

 <div  class="uiInput uiInputSelect forceInputPicklist uiInput--default uiInput--select" >
     <label class="label inputLabel uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel">Products to Price</label>
        <select class=" select" size="6" aria-describedby="" multiple="true" 
           <apex:repeat value="{!MSList}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
             <option label="{!MSList}" />
           </apex:repeat>
         </select>
 </div>
```

The problem I face though is all the values are displayed each line of my multiselect box inside of [] brackets. Is there another variable type I should be using or is this not possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I see the error as I was posting this... I didn't use the right variable in the repeat function. Instead of MSLIST I should be using string.

```
 <div  class="uiInput uiInputSelect forceInputPicklist uiInput--default uiInput--select" >
     <label class="label inputLabel uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel">Products to Price</label>
        <select class=" select" size="6" aria-describedby="" multiple="true" 
           <apex:repeat value="{!MSList}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
             <option label="{!string}" />
           </apex:repeat>
         </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: accept your answers, this way it will be marked as resolved in the forum. thanks